# Installing PS3 controller with RPi

Tags: rpi.gpio

Hi I have been trying to install and work a PS3 controller with my raspberry pi. I want to use it as a joystick to control 2 motors which are speed regulated using ESCs.

I have followed various different install options with no avail. Can someone please help me

I have used:
http://holvin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/how-to-setup-raspberry-pi-as-retro.html

http://www.raspians.com/Knowledgebase/ps3-dualshock-controller-install-on-the-raspberry-pi/

This one worked briefly:
http:// d45h.mx/blog/?p=167
but my idiotic roommate connected it back to the PS3 and now the process wont work again. I was not able to run: jstest /dev/input/js0 to test the controls... but the first time it did register read the controller on the RPi.

Please help! I then want to assign a continuous ESC control to axis 1 any information on that would be appreciated too.